# Make scheduler run in only one instance of multiple micro-service

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, microservices, quartz-scheduler, executorservice, quartz

I have built a micro-service where there is an API called deleteToken. This API(when invoked) is supposed to change the status in a tuple in db corresponding to token (identified with token id) to "MARK-DELETE". Once that tuple has status "MARK_DELETE" then after 30 days there should be a rest call made to downstream service API called deleteTokenFromPartner. There is no such mandate like call to deleteTokenFromPartner has to be made right after 30 days, it can be done few hours later 30 days also. So what I thought was I will write a scheduler (using Quartz, Java Executor service) with scheduled period in such a way that it will run once everyday. what it will do is it will query db and find out all rows which has status="MARK_DELETE" and status update is older than 30 days. After then it will iteratively call deleteTokenFromPartner for each and every row. There is one db which is highly available and we may not have any issue with consistency as we delete after 30 days. But the problem I am seeing is, as this is a micro-service which has N instances so every instance will query db,  get the same set of rows and make call to same rows. Can I make any tweak so that this duplicated calls can be avoided. FYI we don't make any config changes using hostnames and if only one instance will be capable of running the scheduler that too will be fine.

Comment: If you’re using DynamoDB, you could use the TTL feature to handle the deletion, and connect a Lambda to the DynamoDB streams to make the downstream service call exactly once per item that is deleted. This event driven model is very different than what you’ve got, but I think it would eliminate most of the complexity.

Comment: As long as all the microservices instances are sharing the same database and clustered quartz scheduler is used it will make sure only one instance will run the job.Clustering in quartz happen at database level

Comment: @Mathew Pope Can you please elaborate on how can I connect a Lambda to DynamoDB streams to make the downstream service call once per item.